# Angular & RX: improved subscription collection

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

**Update**

After the solution was found I wrote a small helper [ng2-rx-collector](https://github.com/smnbbrv/ng2-rx-collector) based on the accepted answer to make it even easier to use. Hope it helps somebody facing the same problems again and again.

**Original question**

Assume we have a component with two subscriptions on hot observables. We subscribe to them in `ngOnInit` and unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` in order to avoid the memory leaks / unexpected behavior:

```
public ngOnInit() {
  this.s1 = o1.subscribe(console.debug.bind(console));
  this.s2 = o2.subscribe(console.debug.bind(console));
}

public ngOnDestroy() {
  this.s1.unsubscribe();
  this.s2.unsubscribe();
}
```

I love Rx, but I literally want to kill myself every time I need to follow this:

1. Create a private subscription property for each subscription
2. Assign this property to a subscription (this looks really ugly because the real logic goes to the right side)
3. Unsubscribe from each subscription on destroy

Is there any way to improve this?

E.g. in RxSwift they have a `DisposeBag` in order to improve the process, translated to typescript would be:

```
private let bag = DisposeBag();

...

o1.subscribe(...).addDisposableTo(bag);
```

And then only destroying it only once. Problem is that I cannot find any similar `Subscription` function.

Any ideas / hints would be warmly welcomed.

Comment: You can create an array inside a super class and push your subscriptions to this array. Then on super classes `ngOnDestroy` you can `unsubscribe` from the elements of the array.

Comment: This does not solve the problem that I need to wrap the whole observable into brackets etc. I already tried that way and even wrote a small decorator which did it automatically, however it does not really look better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
private teardown$ = new Subject<void>();

public ngOnInit() {
    o1.takeUntil(this.teardown$).subscribe(console.debug.bind(console));
    o2.takeUntil(this.teardown$).subscribe(console.debug.bind(console));
}

public ngOnDestroy() {
   this.teardown$.next();
}
```

Comment: this looks really neat and feels exactly like the thing I am looking for. Thank you very much! Do you know any library which solves the problem by utilising this method?

Comment: You're welcome! I dont know any library yet, but would also be interested in having one.

Comment: https://github.com/smnbbrv/ng2-rx-collector - now you can use it :) If you know some ways to improve it, please let me know...

Answer (score 2):

What you describe used to be called "disposables" in RxJS 4 (correct me if I' wrong) or in RxPHP as well. In RxJS 5 this is called Subscription but the purpose is exactly the same.

In the following example I have two source Observables. I wrap both their unsubscribe calls with a single `Subscription` object that takes a callback as parameter used when calling its `unsubscribe()` method.

```
var source1 = Observable.interval(250);
var source2 = Observable.interval(350);

let sub1 = source1.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
let sub2 = source2.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

let subscriptions = new Subscription(() => {
    sub1.unsubscribe();
    sub2.unsubscribe();
});

setTimeout(() => {
    subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}, 3000);
```

Similarly I can also take the first `Subscription` from `source1.subscribe` and add another `Subscription` that'll be called along with its own `unsubscribe()` call using `add()` method:

```
var source1 = Observable.interval(250);
var source2 = Observable.interval(350);

let subscriptions = source1.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
subscriptions.add(source2.subscribe(val => console.log(val)));

setTimeout(() => {
    subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}, 3000);
```

For more info have a look at the source code: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscription.ts